# Firebase App credentials Error in Flutter Firebase

Tags: flutter

i am integrating the firebase authenitcation to get otp from firebase but when i enter the login button to find the otp from firebase, then a phone verfication page is opening and on that page before otp there is a google captcha  verfication which is verified from the google in android its working good but in ios device its not redirecting to the captcha verification

this error is coming from firebase

**flutter: ERROR otp [firebase_auth/invalid-app-credential] Invalid token**

flutter: ERROR otp [firebase_auth/invalid-app-credential] Invalid token